# Translating between Python-Django and Javascript

Tags: javascript, django, translate

The problem is that will be several translated (languages) javascript files and I need to create each one with `django-admin.py makemessages -d djangojs -l + language`. So, I need to learn about how each translated file would be named and accessed. Regards.

Example:

```
{

"sEmptyTable": "No data available in table", 
 "sInfo": "Showing START to END of TOTAL entries",
 "sInfoEmpty": "Showing 0 to 0 of 0 entries",
 "sInfoFiltered": "(filtered from MAX total entries)",
 "sInfoPostFix": "", 
 "sInfoThousands": ",", 
 "sLengthMenu": "Show MENU entries", 
 "sLoadingRecords": "Loading...", 
 "sProcessing": "Processing...", 
 "sSearch": "Search:", 
 "sZeroRecords": "No matching records found",
}`
```

Comment: What exactly is the question? What is the relevance of the example to the naming scheme?

Comment: I'm doing a translation of my website in multiple languages​​. The base file is in English. 
I found difficulty in translating Javascript files by generating the file djangojs.po. Should I use gettext () ?